# webpack-dev-server getting complied but no output file is created?

Tags: javascript, webpack

webpack-dev-server is getting compiled but not creating any output file while using simple webpack it is creating the file. Why?

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
   entry: "./src/app.js",
   output: {
     path: path.join(__dirname, "/public/"), //file path name
     filename: "bundles.js" //this is not getting created
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
       {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_ modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader" //loader
       }
     ]
   },
   devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
   devServer: {
     contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
     compress: true,
     port: 9000
   }
};
```

It should create bundle.js
and it is not giving any compile time error as well it shows it's compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option called `writeToDisk`
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-